# ¿por qué se muestra en el TextView "salida" el valor 0 en lugar del ancho de la imagen?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Estoy haciendo un simple programa en el que se muestra una imagen al arrancar la aplicación, y necesito saber las coordenadas exactas, la altura y la anchura en tiempo de ejecución. La cuestión es que en el método OnCreate no consigo que me muestre en pantalla dichos valores. Me muestra el valor cero.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener{
    TextView x;
    TextView salida;
    ImageView barra;
    ImageView linea;

    int y, h_barra, y_barra, alto;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        x = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.x);
        salida = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.salida);

        barra = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.barra);
        linea = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.linea);

        salida.setText(Integer.toString(barra.getWidth()));

        barra.setOnTouchListener(this);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Te recomiendo describir tu problema en el cuerpo de la pregunta para que así quede mas claro.

Comment: gracias, lo hago

Comment: esto responde tu pregunta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680499/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-android-widget-imageview

Comment: Funciona, fenómeno

Comment: jajjaja fenómeno ?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se llama el método `onCreate()` aún se esta creando la UI, en ese momento no puedes obtener las medidas, si tratas de realizar esto, en este punto obtendrás valor de 0, debes obtenerlas después de que se realizo la construcción.

Mediante la clase [ViewTreeObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) puedes crear un listener para detectar el momento en el cual se termino de dibujar la UI y en este momento tener las propiedades correctas, en este caso la medida.

```
final TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_textview);

ViewTreeObserver vto = textview.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    public boolean onPreDraw() {        
        textview.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        int alturaVista = textview.getMeasuredHeight();
        int anchoVista = textview.getMeasuredWidth();
        Log.i("Medidas", "El TextView tiene una altura: " + alturaVista + " y un ancho: " + anchoVista );
        return true;
    }
});
```